# Justify images inside div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a centered div that takes 80% of the width of window, inside that div  have a gallery images `.container img {min-width:200px;}` using jquery I want to make the images justified depending on the width of the `.container`, the code that worked for me is this :

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){

        // get the width of the container
        var albumContentWidth = $(".container").width();

        // as we have in our css the min-width of image is 200
        // see how many image can fit in each row
        var imagePerRow = parseInt(albumContentWidth / 200);

        // set the width of image using calc
        $(".container img").css("width", "calc(100% / #{imagePerRow})");

});
```

The code above works fine, but for some reasons.. I don't want to use calc() instead I want to calculate this using pixels, so what I did :

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){

        // get the width of the container
        var albumContentWidth = $(".container").width();

        // as we have in our css the min-width of image is 200
        // see how many image can fit in each row
        var imagePerRow = parseInt(albumContentWidth / 200);

        // instead of using calc() divide the width of container by the possible number of images per row
        var imageWidth = (albumContentWidth / imagePerRow).toFixed(2);

        // set the width of image using calc
        $(".container img").css("width", imageWidth);

});
```

However this is not working and the images don't get justified correctly when I resize !!

Comment: The question is why are you using jquery to do this when you possibly can do this with simple CSS ?

Comment: you should use flexbox

Comment: @ArtemSky flex has the disadvantage that if there is only one element at row it will make it center, I already tried flex with `justify-content: space-between` but as i said it does make elements centered when there is only one or two elements per line...

Comment: @DaniP I think my question isn't enough clear I write it while I have a headache lol I will rewrite it again with a jsfiddle so you can see :) I don't want to use css "flex" nor media queries, because both don't achieve what i wanna do